# Снижение загрузки ЦП при выполнении цикла (C++)

Tags: c++, циклы, cpu

Видеосервер на C++ непрерывно в отдельном потоке подготавливает кадры для дальнейшей записи видео. Склеиваются несколько источников (камер) и помещаются на результирующий кадр сеткой (2х2, 4х3, 5х4 и т.п.), а так как  этот кадр представляет собой просто буфер `unsigned char *`, то для корректного позиционирования в нём все кадры-источники нужно писать в этот буфер по линиям (ширина * количество_цветов), рассчитывая смещение для каждой линии.

Так вот этот цикл записи загружает ЦП в среднем на ~25% (причём не важно - что Xeon-E5, что Core i-3 - одинаковые показатели загрузки), а мне нужно иметь возможность наплодить таких потоков штук 10 как минимум (пока лимит 3). Вариант с `Sleep(1)` в конце каждой итерации записи линии не прокатывает, так как тогда FPS будет примерно 1 кадр в 10 секунд, что недопустимо.

Грузящий ЦП цикл выглядит так:

```
for(unsigned short l = 0; l < Image.Height(); l++){
    unsigned long iX = x*SD.line + X_pad + SD.X_offset;
    unsigned long iY = (y*SD.height+l)*CANVAS.Line() + Y_pad + SD.Y_offset;
    memcpy(CANVAS.Data(iX+iY), Image.Data(l*Image.Line()), Image.Line());

    // Sleep(1); работает, но не вариант - сильно страдает FPS
}
```

**Можно ли как-то снизить нагрузку на ЦП в данной ситуации?**

Comment: А что говорит профайлер? На вскидку - я бы вынес за цикл все что не меняется - например iX, Image.Line(), CANVAS.Line() и т.д. Но подозреваю, что оптимизация это уже проделала... Потому интересно посмотреть именно на рекомендации профайлера.

Comment: А этот цикл у вас крутится постоянно, независимо от того, появился у камеры новый кадр или нет?

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky , да оптимизация уже проделана, да и эти расчёты не влияют на загрузку - грузит именно циклический `memcpy`. С профайлером, честно, не работал - надо попробовать, спасибо за подсказку

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, один постоянно - каждые 30 секунд меняя набор камер рандомно. Остальные такие же потоки уже вызываются пользователями и содержат личную выборку камер. Выборку крутят постоянно, пока их смотрят. Клиентские jpeg-кадры записываются в `std::string`, при подготовке цикла поток под мьютексом обходит `std::map` клиентов, записывая нужных в свой набор, и затем, в цикле уже постоянно крутит этот свой набор.

Comment: Если вам sleep не подходит только из за того, что он минимум секунда, возьмите usleep. Хотя в идеале конечно надо спать до тех пора пока не появились новые данные для обработки ...

Comment: @Iceman то есть молотит он и когда новых данных нет. Смотрите в эту сторону, думаю, производительно вырастет очень хорошо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sleep обычно маскирует проблемы и временно снимает симптомы. Само по себе скопировать FullHD иили 4к кадр через memcpy не одожно тормозить Core i3. Обычно если тормозит, то проблемы могут быть в следующем:

1. Цикл с memcpy молотит даже тогда когда нет изменений в картинке. Возможно вам следует слать сигнал/событие когда надо перерисоваться.
2. Разные камеры посылают сигнал не перерисовку в разное время и вы перересовываете всю картинку, вместо измененной области. Сделайте жесткую синхронизацию - "пробуждайте" (не sleep, а сигнал/событие) функцию перересовки не чаще 1/25 секунды
3. Возможно вы блокируете UI поток слишком на долго каким-нибудь мьтексом и вам кажется что программа тормозит, т.к. нет реакции на действи пользователя.

Про профайлер, вам уже написале. Можно использовать профайтер для бедных:

```
auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
for(unsigned short l = 0; l < Image.Height(); l++){
    unsigned long iX = x*SD.line + X_pad + SD.X_offset;
    unsigned long iY = (y*SD.height+l)*CANVAS.Line() + Y_pad + SD.Y_offset;
    memcpy(CANVAS.Data(iX+iY), Image.Data(l*Image.Line()), Image.Line());

    // Sleep(1); работает, но не вариант - сильно страдает FPS
}
auto finish = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(finish-start).count() << "ns\n";
```

Это дешевый способ убедиться что memcpy не тормозит

Comment: По поводу пункта 3 - программа не тормозит, всё работает плавно. Просто одно ядро (поток) получает 100% нагрузку (если в i3 4 потока) - получается 25%, я так понимаю. Проблема в том, что нужно иметь возможность запустить таких циклов в параллельных потоках больше 3 до 100% загрузки всего ЦП. Также выяснилось, что при комментировании цикла записи кадра загрузка не снизилась... Я вообще в ступоре... ))

Comment: @iceman, Может обработка видео потока от камеры ест эти %%? Если это так, то возможно камера жрет все предоставленое время в потоке с низким приоритетом, тогда это ничего страшного.

Comment: Камеры приходят по сокетам, сам сервер ничего не снимает, только опрашивает кадры клиентов в `map` под мьютексом. Я попробовал снять лимит и запросить столько потоков, сколько надо - проц 99%, но система работает нормально, тормоза на стримах практически не ощущаются... Значит ли это, что всё нормально и не помешает другим приложениям в системе, например апачу и серверу mysql?

Comment: @iceman, В общем случае "нет, не значит". Если вы не понимаете кто есть 99%, то могут быть такие варианты. 1) Кто-то с пониженным приоритетом есть CPU, другие серверные процессы так же могут запускать тяжелые задачи с низким приоритетом, которые будут конкурировать за эти 99%. 2) при увелечение количества потоков, которые требуют планировщика,  поднимаются load average и при большем их количестве, даже с пониженым приоритетом, начинают влиять на общую производительность сервера. 3) Самое банальное. Это вам кажется что система работает нормально, но возможно она на пределе.